# insert multiple rows using eloquent

Tags: php, database, eloquent

So I'm trying to do an array insert of multiple rows using eloquent, but I don't see any obvious way to do this in the docs. So I don't know if there's a best practice way, or if I should just for-each my way through those inserts. Does anybody know of oa smarter way?

It's only rows in a relationstable with both columns being foreign keys referencing the same primary key in another table.

Comment: If you are adding pivot table data, then look to use the `sync` method. [More info from the docs](http://laravel.com/docs/database/eloquent#inserting-related-models)

Answer (score -1):

You can use the insert method to multiple rows as shown here http://jasonlewis.me/article/laravel-and-eloquent-part-1-basics

Comment: This link appears to be dead an the time of writing. Comments but no article.